# Word 2007 VBA Page Orientation to Landscape not working

Tags: vba

I've written a Word 2007 macro to setup the page and change the orientation.    All of the settings works EXCEPT changing the document from Portrait to Landscape.     (You can see in the code below I'm setting it twice.)

```
With Selection.PageSetup
    .LineNumbering.Active = False
    .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
    .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.8)
    .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
    .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.6)
    .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(8.5)
    .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(11)
    .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
    .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
    .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
    .SuppressEndnotes = False
    .MirrorMargins = False
    .TwoPagesOnOne = False
    .BookFoldPrinting = False
    .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
    .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
    .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
End With


ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
```

After my code I enter a table and do more formatting - but only to the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: put breakpoint on the `.Orientation` statements. Review your macro stepping through these statements using F8. Do you observe the document orientation changing (as expected)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing a multipage document maybe you need to make sure the page you are trying to format is in a section all by itself. 
Have you tried putting section breaks in front of and after the page you are working on, and then trying to set the orientation?